# Problem about Integration of several orthogonal polynomials

Tags: integration, interpolation, orthogonal-polynomials

In the literature, there are several orthogonal polynomials, like Hermite Polynomials, Legendre Polynomials. However, I would like to ask whether there are any explicit formulas for the integration of several Orthogonal polynomials. For example, I want to calculate the integration
$$\int_{-1}^1\prod_{i=1}^k L_i(x)w(x)dx $$
where, $L_i(x)$ is Legendre polynomials and  $w(x) = 1$ is the corresponding weight function, $k$ is the number of polynomials. I want to know how to calculate the integration when the number of polynomials $k=3,4$, especially for  $k=4$. I want to know there are some explicit expression for integration.  Are there tables/references where I can find the results? Besides, I also want to know the integration in the cases of Hermite, Laguerre and Chebyshev polynomials.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The families of orthogonal polynomials you list are all examples of *classical* orthogonal polynomials. They all have explicit expressions for their coefficients so you can write them out and do the integration explicitly.

For Legendre we have
$$
P_n(x)  = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}\binom{\frac{n+m-1}{2},n}x^m,
$$
so we get
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} dx \prod_{n=0}^k P_n(x)
=
\prod_{n=0}^k \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1-(-1)^{m+1}}{m+1}
\binom{n}{m}  
\binom{(n+m-1)/2 }{n}.
$$